# Installing xgboost in R 2.12

Tags: r, installation, xgboost

i tried to install `xgboost` using `CRAN` in `R`. I am using windows 7 and `R2.12.2` and i am encountering the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘xgboost’ is not available

Checking the available packages, true enough, `xgboost` is not included.
Can anyone help me install this package to R?
I can update my R to newer version because some of my applications currently uses 2.12. Thank you

Comment: 2.12.2 is waaaaay old version... you'd better update soon... you will eventually need to update all your applications one day in any case... The applications running in 2.12.2 should ideally be reprogrammed for latest versions... That's the only way to go about it

Comment: Agree, i have to update them sooner. I just wanted to know if xgboost installation works for versions of R such as the version that i have. Just to test some of the functionalityies that i am currently working on. Would you know?please?thank you

Comment: The cran document says it works on 2.10 and higher, but it also has many other dependencies like, which I guess do not support the older versions anymore

Comment: R v 2.12.2 was released *more than five years ago*. I wouldn't waste my time trying to install anything on such a deprecated version. I recommend updating R, as @Gaurav suggested.

Comment: Cool. Thanks everyone. Appreciate it.